# SQLite DB structure with multiple elements in column

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I want to create a DB to store some information for an app/game that uses geo coordinates. I'm using java with SQLite for that purpose.
I need a table which stores information like the following:

USER_TABLE:
Username,
Password,
Points,
Areas (consisting of multiple points per area),
Achievements (can consist of multiple entries, for the ones unlocked)

Areas and achievements should also have unique ID's so I can check whether a certain achievement is unlocked by a player, or to see if a certain area(consisting of multiples points) belongs to a user, so they should look like:

AREAS_TABLE:
Area_ID,
Points (which consists of all latitude/longitude or X/Y points of that area),
(MAYBE) belonging User(attribute to relate to the user the area belongs to),

ACHIEVEMENTS_TABLE:
Achievement_ID,
Achievement_Name,

My question is now: How can I store the information of multiple points per single Area? Do I have to store them all in two Strings for X and Y so that the entries look like this:

X = x1, x2, x3, x4, ..,
Y = y1, y2, y3, y4, ...

or is it possible to somehow elegantly store them in a single area-construct  like a table:
Single_area:
Lantitude/X,
Longitude/Y,

Heres a pictures of the relations I need:
The circled attributes are attributes that multiple entries can exist of, like MULTIPLE users: one user has a name, a password, a score and MULTIPLE areas. Areas consist of MULTIPLE points..
[image: Thats a diagram of the relations I need]

Comment: Why not properly normalized with a Points table?

Comment: Thats my question. Im still trying to figure out how to do this with SQLite and Java. A user can have n-areas and an area can have n-points. The order of points is relevant. Do you mean there should be a table where ALL points are consistent which I can look up with an area-ID?